# Event wont work with user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, events, delegates

I have a problem that I can't resolve on the server side of my project.

I'll explain:

I have a page named Global,this is ASP.NET page.
This page uses a UserControl named CateGories.
Now I have a button on this UC page,that when I press I want to invoke a function on the Global page that makes a connection with my DB.

I decided to use delegates(events)

This is the code.

Global page:

//here i add my function to the event

```
protected  void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ShowCurrentTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
        CateGories ClassCat = new CateGories();
        ClassCat.MainDel += PopulateLinks;
    }
```

//this is the function that the event will run

```
 public void PopulateLinks(string CategoryName)
    {....}
```

Code of the UC page (CateGories):

//delegation of the event

```
public delegate void Click(string ButtonName);
public event Click MainDel = null;
```

//function that invokes when I click a button

```
protected void News_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MainDel != null)
        {
            MainDel(News.Text);
        }
    }
```

Now everythig should work fine, but there is a problem, when the compiler gets to the 
`if(MainDel!=null)`
...

It doesn't get in the function, there go MainDel is null. 
I can't see the problem here, why after I insert function to MainDel, its gets null eventualy...

I'll be happy if someone can help
thanks.
Max.

Comment: Still looking here, but couldn't miss the `CateGories`. Is this a new way of naming?

Comment: It was by mistake the capital 'G' :)

Comment: No worries man. It happens. :) But I can't find a way on helping you out.

Comment: Np,i will wait,maybe someone will find the problem,thanx anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've encountered this problem before, when working with web applications the way I would a windows application.

The problem lies in that when the page gets reloaded, a new instance of your page class is created so any values from the last server interaction are lost.

Comment: Can you give me an example?,i never used viewstate,i guess its like a Cache.

Comment: You are correct!,indeed the reference were to the null! i made a function that create an instance and adds to the event the needed function,and invokes the event.

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out. I searched around, seems that you cannot store a deligate in viewstate. Initiating it in a function like you did would be the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

MainDel is indeed null for what I can see.

You're creating one instance of CateGories on your Web Form and another one on your User Control. And once you check it for beeing null on the UC the reference is to the not initialized object.

One possible way to do that is creating and adding the User Control programatically to the page before PageLoad() and keeping a reference to it so you can access it's properties.

Another solution could be using Page.FindControl to find the UC and make the subscription to the event.

The method names above may be incorrect, it's been a long time without working with web forms.

Comment: This is a good theory,but i made other program's with similar code and it worked,so i can't understand why it doesn't work here.